# Здравствуйте, подскажите как проверить БД на наличие значения в ней? Что-то не получается

Tags: php, pdo

```
<?php
error_reporting (-1);
ini_set ('display errors', 1);


require_once 'D:\OpenSer\OpenServer\domains\restAPI\ClassModel\PDOConnect.php';
require_once 'D:\OpenSer\OpenServer\domains\restAPI\ClassModel\FormConnect.php';


class WriteDB
{
    public $pDOConnect;
    public $formConnect;


    public function __construct ()// обЪект ПДО добавить
    {
        $this->formConnect = new FormConnect;
        $this->formConnect -> CreateForm($_POST);
        $this->pDOConnect = new pDOConnect;
        $this->pDOConnect->CreatePDO();
   }

   public function Write()
   {
        $sel = $this->pDOConnect->pdo->prepare("SELECT `name` FROM `apin` WHERE `name`=':name'");
        $sel->execute(array('name' => $this->formConnect->name));
        $selas=$sel->fetch();

        if($selas)
        {
            echo "Пользователь существует";
            exit();
        }   

        $wr = $this->pDOConnect->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO apin(name,familie,fatername,phone,mail) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
        $wr->execute(array($this->formConnect->name, $this->formConnect->familie, $this->formConnect->fatername, $this->formConnect->phone, $this->formConnect->mail));
    
        echo "Вы зарегистрированы";
    
    }

}




?>
```

Comment: А чем вас текущий код не устраивает?

Comment: Не проверяет на наличие значения в БД, ошибок не выдает.

Comment: ну как же не проверяет?! Вот же `if ($selas) { echo "Пользователь существует";`

Comment: ))) Ну да. Только вместо проверки регистрирует еще раз.

Comment: Ну значит запись не существует

Comment: Существует. В нескольких экземплярах уже, и исправно выдает сообщение об успешной регистрации.

Comment: вы, надеюсь, exception режим поставили для PDO. Ибо у вас явная ошибка в запросе. Вы экранируете `name`, хотя за вас это делает PDO. получаются повторяющиеся кавычки

Comment: Спасибо, переделал запрос. Все работает. Для меня кавычки в PHP - боль и печаль))).